# SED: read from file and replace after

Tags: sed

So I have next files:

```
user@host:sandbox$ cat readfile.txt
READ LINE
E
A
D

T
E
X
T
```

and

```
user@host:sandbox$ cat template.txt
set variable = blablabla
```

I need a command that brings together the following two commands:

```
user@host:sandbox$ sed -e '/set variable/r readfile.txt' template.txt > output.txt
user@host:sandbox$ cat output.txt
set variable = blablabla
READ LINE
E
A
D

T
E
X
T
user@host:sandbox$ sed -e 's/READ LINE/BLABLABLA/' output.txt > output.txt.m
user@host:sandbox$ cat output.txt.m
set variable = blablabla
BLABLABLA
E
A
D

T
E
X
T
```

Something like (however this does not work):

```
user@host:sandbox$ sed -e '/set variable/{r readfile.txt' -e 's/READ LINE/BLABLABLA/}' template.txt > output.txt
```

Guru of SED, I need help!

Comment: Are "blablabla" and "BLABLABLA" related, i.e. do you want to use the variable value uppper-cased as the replacement?

Comment: are you looking something like this... $cat template.txt readfile.txt | sed 's/READ LINE/BLABLABLA/g' > output.txt

Comment: No, this are not related.

Comment: This is a special case of a large task, which uses multiple -e expression of several template files

Answer (score 3):

sed manual says about read file command not included for "Commands which accept address ranges"
Therefore the next solution will be correct:

```
user@host:sandbox$ sed -e '/set variable/r readfile.txt' template.txt > output.txt
user@host:sandbox$ sed -i 's/READ LINE/BLABLABLA/' output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to append the file you can just use `cat` itself.

`cat template.txt readfile.txt > output.txt`

If you need a specific line or lines from one you can select the lines using `sed` with process substitution (in Bash).

e.g. To take lines 3-5 and line 7 from template.txt and append readfile.txt:
`cat <(sed -n '3,5p;7p' template.txt) readfile.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/READ LINE/BLABLABLA/' readfile.txt | 
sed '/set variable/r /dev/stdin' template.txt > output.txt
```

This first edits the `readfile.txt` and passes this file via a pipe to the the second sed command that edits the `template.txt`

N.B. a file read(`r`) into another cannot be processed because it is passed directly to stdout after the sed command has been processed. Similarly to the output of the line number using the `=` command.